# How to select rows that meet multiple criteria from a column?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste the rows based on column A that appear in column B to a new sheet (e.g. copy and paste all rows that contain 1, 2 and 7 in column A to a new sheet). I know a less smart way using macro. I believe using a nested loop will make life easier (when column B is a long list), however, mine did not work. Please see my LessSmartWay code and FailedSmartWay code below.

The table looks like this:

```
A   B   C   D  
1   1   a   1/1/2015  
1   2   b   1/2/2015  
1   7   c   1/3/2015  
2   -   a   1/4/2015  
3   -   b   1/5/2015  
3   -   c   1/6/2015  
3   -   a   1/7/2015  
3   -   b   1/8/2015  
4   -   c   1/9/2015  
4   -   a   1/10/2015  
5   -   b   1/11/2015  
5   -   c   1/12/2015  
6   -   a   1/13/2015  
6   -   b   1/14/2015  
6   -   c   1/15/2015  
7   -   a   1/16/2015  
7   -   b   1/17/2015  
7   -   c   1/18/2015
```

.

```
Sub LessSmartWay()    
    Set t = Sheets("test")
    Set r = Sheets("select")
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    d = 1
    j = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(t.Range("A" & j))
    If t.Range("A" & j) = t.Range("B2") Or t.Range("A" & j) = t.Range("B3") Or t.Range("A" & j) = t.Range("B4") Then
    d = d + 1
    r.Rows(d).Value = t.Rows(j).Value
    End If
    j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

.

```
Sub FailedSmartWay()
    Set t = Sheets("test")
    Set r = Sheets("select")
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    d = 1
    j = 2
    i = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(t.Range("B" & i))
        Do Until IsEmpty(t.Range("A" & j))
        If t.Range("A" & j) = t.Range("B" & i) Then
        d = d + 1    
        r.Rows(d).Value = t.Rows(j).Value
        End If
        j = j + 1
        Loop
      i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Same can be accomplished by using filter in column A.

Comment: If Column B has 100, I do not want to click 100 times by using filter in column A. This is why I am trying to use macro. Thanks.

Comment: What should the output be? By your code it would have 7 lines all the rows with 1,2 or 7 in column A.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Scott This is correct.

Comment: Then @jeffCarey answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the j value each time you iterate through the outer loop

```
Do Until IsEmpty(t.Range("B" & i))
    ' Insert this line here
    j = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(t.Range("A" & j))
    If t.Range("A" & j) = t.Range("B" & i) Then
    d = d + 1    
    r.Rows(d).Value = t.Rows(j).Value
    End If
    j = j + 1
    Loop
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple For/Each loops iterating over a Range.  It just seems a bit cleaner.

```
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim LastRowB As Long

Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wks2 As Worksheet
Set wks = WB.Sheets("test")
Set wks2 = WB.Sheets("select")

LastRowA = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).ROW
LastRowB = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).ROW

Dim rowRangeA As Range
Dim rowRangeB As Range
Set rowRangeA = wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)
Set rowRangeB = wks.Range("B1:B" & LastRowB)

' keep track of our current line on second worksheet
Dim currentEndingRow As Integer
currentEndingRow = 1

For Each mCellA In rowRangeA
    'Our nested loop, will cycle through each row in B once for every row in A.
    For Each mCellB In rowRangeB
        If mCellA.Value = mCellB.Value Then
           'wks2.Cells(currentEndingRow, 1).Value = mCellA.Value
            wks2.Rows(currentEndingRow).Value = wks.Rows(mCellB.Row).Value
            currentEndingRow = currentEndingRow + 1
        End If
    Next mCellB
' Move on to the next Row A after it finishes the last row in B.
Next mCellA
```

Comment: Can you explain how mCellA (or mCellB) works? I did not see you define it? If I want to copy the whole row to the "select", I guess we need to tweak this line a little bit "wks2.Cells(currentEndingRow, 1).Value = mCellA.Value". How to change this? Thanks.

Comment: mCellA is defined within the For Each loop automatically, its definition is implied by just simply creating the For Loop.  I commented out my original code before I saw you wanted the whole row copied over.  What I have on there now will do the trick for copying the entire row, and not just a single cell.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful!